# Error: Main method not found in class, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: selenium

As my question is old but am new eclipse am not able to solve the error.
can someone help in solving this.

```
public class Anita {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.get("https://www.hdfc.com/");
       WebElement Housing = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Housing Loans"));
       Actions myActions = new Actions(driver);
       myActions.moveToElement(Housing);

    }

}
```

When I execute above code, I got this error.

> Main method not found in class, please define the main method
>   as:public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application
>   class must extend javafx.application.Application

and why I need to extend javafx appilcation? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to execute on another class.

Open the class `Anita` in eclipse editor.

Right click on the class in editor > Run As > Java Application

If the main method is not found you will not be able to see the Java Application option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sighil.Before am able to see java application but now the error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just save your work (Ctrl + s) then run again. Trust me, it all works! Thank me later :)